# Error updating Android Studio Gradle from 4.0.2 to 4.1.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I faced problem of updating Gradle from 4.0.2 to 4.1.0 in my Android Studio. My Android Studio Version is **4.1**

Here is the error occurred:

---

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#.
> Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class java.lang.String] due to overlapping prototypes between:
> [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]
> [class java.io.File, class java.lang.String]

---

I tried to google possible solution but mostly is just above Groovy. Does anyone face this problem when updating Gradle too?

Comment: I have encountered this problem also...

Comment: By saying "Updating gradle from 4.0.2 to 4.1", did you mean version of gradle itself or version of Android gradle plugin?. I guess you mean Android gradle plugin

Comment: Also you haven't provided us with enough details, where does this method get referenced? Can you share more about code that uses this method

Comment: Hi all, finally I figured out my problem. 

It is caused by Sentry Android library. Sentry Android seems to have problem with android 4.1.0 and recently they update their Sentry gradle to 1.7.36. I tried and now I successfully on Android gradle 4.1.0 ! :)

Anyone using Sentry Android please update your Sentry gradle to 1.7.36 in order to update to Android gradle 4.1.0. Thank you!

Comment: @MR3YY I mean Android gradle plugin. the error was coming with Sentry groove exception. It was my fault forget to upload details screenshot. Eventually I solved it by asking on official github repo and the author replied me with solutuon. Thanks for your time as well :)